# How safe is Baltimore Washington Airport Amtrak station at night?

Tags: train-stations, amtrak, maryland, baltimore, bwi

I am taking Amtrak train from New York Penn Station to Baltimore Washington International Airport **Amtrak** station next month. I am reaching BWI Airport Amtrak station at 2AM. After getting down from the train, I plan to take a cab to one of the hotels nearby.

How safe is it? Are there people in the station at that time, or is the place deserted?

Added from Comments

> I just plan to get off the train and catch one of the cabs (either
>   Uber/Lyft or one of the local cabs waiting in line) right away. I
>   don't intend on waiting/staying back in the station.

Comment: At 2am there may be be bwi employees going home after shift. There are much scarier places in Baltimore proper; I'd have no qualms with this plan as long as I pre-ordered a cab or planned on walking to the concourse proper to hail one.

Comment: How are we supposed to answer "how safe"? I would say it is very safe, but I don't know if your baseline is the same as mine, so you might feel unsafe in the same situation. The taxi drivers know when the trains arrive, and there is always a line of them there waiting, and the station area is patrolled by county police, but certainly there is theft and maybe worse in the parking garage across the drive.

Comment: @choster I think as long as there are Amtrak/Airport staff in the station, it should be fine. I will post my experience after my trip so that this post can help others who might have the same query in the future.

Comment: Part of being safe is being confident. Looking anxious can be a self-fulfilling state of mind.

Comment: @Dashamlav The station will be closed and there will be no Amtrak or airport staff present at that hour.

Comment: Please see https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3314/asking-a-good-safety-question and https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1906/personal-safety

Comment: Amtrak has their own police and a small detachment always on site. Now depending on your politics that might make you feel less or more safe. Also at most Amtrak stations, homeless folks are not allowed to make their residence.